# get company description in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffold

I have a table Company with companyid and companyname, and a table Config for my company configuration that have id, companyid, companyname, config that is in my dropdown generate by rails g scaffold

how can I override/change Ruby's Save/create button on creating my new config?
 Is it right to have my companyname on the config table or is it better to remove it and have a method geyCompanyName(id)?

I'm new to Ruby and just trying to follow the tutorial

Controller looks like

```
 def index
@company_config = CompanyConfig.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @company_config }
end
end


def show
@@company_config = CompanyConfig.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @company_config }
end
end


 def new
@company_config = ComapnyConfig.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @company_config }
end
end


def edit
 @company_config = CompanyConfig.find(params[:id])
end

def create
@company_config =  CompanyConfig.new(params[:company_config])

respond_to do |format|
  if @company_config.save
    format.html { redirect_to @company_config, notice: 'Config was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @company_config, status: :created, location: @company_config }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @@company_config.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end
```

I tried to look on Controller create but not sure how to edit it to meet what I want to accomplish.

my view looks like

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company_config) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :companyid, collection:build_company_select_array %>
  <%= f.input :companyname %>


 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: There's too little information to answer the question. What have you tried? What didn't work? What does your view look like? What does your controller look like?

Comment: You should tag this as ruby-on-rails, not ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT have information like `companyname` stored in two places.

The only thing you need in your CompanyConfig model is the id, the company_id, and any other information you want to store about the company that's appropriate to a configuration record.

And you can have Company defined so that it `has_one company_config` (or `has_many company_configs`) and CompanyConfig defined so it `belongs_to company`

When you want to reference the company name, it's accessible by `my_company_config.company.companyname` although you'll eventually learn to delegate methods.  A very simple example...

```
class CompanyConfig
  belongs_to company
  def companyname
    company.companyname
  end
end
```

... which will give you the ability to do `my_company_config.companyname` but still store the data in only one place.

Comment: thanks I accepted the answer and have coded it just like your suggestion